# Is there a meta tag or something for desktops that works like viewport initial-scale?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meta-tags

I know you're thinking that this is a strange request, however I am currently dealing with a client that gave me a template and decided he wanted it 70% smaller after seeing it in a browser and all the HTML done (**!!!!**). Thus throwing all the work that was done for both of us out the window. If I could adjust the scale to 0.7 (70%) that would be perfect and the project can still roll out the way it was going. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
body {
zoom: 0.7;
transform: scale(0.7);
transform-origin:0 0;
-ms-transform: scale(0.7);
-ms-transform-origin:0 0;
-moz-transform: scale(0.7);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.7);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I just thought of that when I was in the shower. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the CSS Zoom property but negativly? - supported in IE 5.5+, Opera, and Safari 4, and Chrome (verifed, please check before downvoting).

Firefox is the only major browser that does not support Zoom ([Check here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390936)) but you could use the ["proprietary" -moz-transform property in Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/CSS_transform_functions#scale).

So you could use:

```
div.zoomed { zoom: 70%; -moz-transform: scale(.7); }
```

Comment: Nice one on the zoom property. His boss will most like be using IE6 or something :-). You only have the value incorrect. It accepts a percentage, so zoom: 70%. And scale(.7); Change it and you get a vote up