# Why does meta tag injection not work for deskop browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code in my java-script:

```
function initScreen() {
    isMobile = (/iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry/).test(navigator.userAgent);
    isTablet = (/iPad/).test(navigator.userAgent);
    if(isMobile) {
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.30, maximum-scale=0.50, minimum-scale=0.25, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">').appendTo('head');
    } else if(isTablet) {
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.95, maximum-scale=0.95, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">').appendTo('head');
    } else {
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.80, maximum-scale=0.80, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">').appendTo('head');
    }
}
```

which is called by my index.html at startup:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initScreen();
    });
</script>
</head>
```

this just works fine for my iPad and on iPhones and Android based mobiles. But when opened on my desktop with firefox, chrome and safari, the "meta" tag does not show any effect. I already tried to substitute the commas with semicolons, but no effect...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to the desktop versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari, `<meta name="viewport">` is ignored in most, if not all, desktop browsers.

> *Note: The viewport meta tag is ignored on desktop versions of Firefox.*
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Firefox_Mobile_for_developers

Similar on Stack Overflow:

[Does Viewport affect desktop browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333535/does-viewport-affect-desktop-browsers)

[How do desktop browsers handle mobile meta tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350225/how-do-desktop-browsers-handle-mobile-meta-tags)

Comment: Depends on which part of the viewport tag you want. For initial-scale you could use CSS `zoom` and `transform`. Maybe you will find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432581/is-there-a-meta-tag-or-something-for-desktops-that-works-like-viewport-initial-s